# Successfully calling an API using fetch, but can't pull individual values from object

Tags: javascript, fetch

I am successfully able to call the API and get the full list to display in the console. However, when I try to pull out single elements, I get "undefined". I can not see what I am doing wrong. Below is my code:

```
let myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("X-eBirdApiToken", "someToken");

let requestOptions = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: myHeaders,
    redirect: 'follow'
};

class Birds {
    constructor(region) {
        this.region = 'US-MA'
    }

    async getBirds() {
        const response = await fetch(`https://api.ebird.org/v2/data/obs/${this.region}/recent`, requestOptions);
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log(data);
        console.log(data.comName);
        console.log(data["locId"]);

        const {speciesCode, comName} = data;
        console.log(speciesCode, comName)

        return data;
    }
}
```

Below is a sample output from the API as I am getting 283 rows:

```
281:
comName: "Catharus sp."
howMany: 1
lat: 42.219
lng: -71.064
locId: "L207351"
locName: "Blue Hills Reservation"
locationPrivate: false
obsDt: "2020-07-10 11:50"
obsReviewed: false
obsValid: true
sciName: "Catharus sp."
speciesCode: "cathus"
subId: "S71320255"

__proto__:
constructor: ƒ Object()
hasOwnProperty: ƒ hasOwnProperty()
isPrototypeOf: ƒ isPrototypeOf()
propertyIsEnumerable: ƒ propertyIsEnumerable()
toLocaleString: ƒ toLocaleString()
toString: ƒ toString()
valueOf: ƒ valueOf()
__defineGetter__: ƒ __defineGetter__()
__defineSetter__: ƒ __defineSetter__()
__lookupGetter__: ƒ __lookupGetter__()
__lookupSetter__: ƒ __lookupSetter__()
get __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
set __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
```

And when I try to get the individual items:

```
undefined
birds.js:20 undefined
birds.js:23 undefined undefined
```

Comment: Please provide the output of `console.log(data)`.

Comment: Add the `data` object, what you got after console-logging.

Comment: "*pull individual items from list*" - nothing in the code you posted does access a list?! Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/11922383/1048572

Comment: Thanks @Bergi that was super helpful and thorough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line shows that you're trying to deconstruct a single object,

```
 const {speciesCode, comName} = data;
```

However, data is an array! So instead, if you want to console log, you need to do,

```
 const {speciesCode, comName} = data[0];
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved the question. However, I know realize I was trying to skip a step. I need to run a for loop first, and then work with the individual objects.